# Why is my WiFi file copy so slow?

Tags: networking, lan, speed, wifi-configuration, dual-band

I have shared a folder on my **Debian 8 GNU/Linux**  PC using Samba network sharing service. The folder is on an **external hard disk** that is connected to the PC using an **USB 3.0** cable. The PC is connected to a **Linksys x3500** router using a CAT6 LAN cable which the PC reports that it has **1 Gbps** connection speed.
 I have also a **Lenovo X1 Carbon** laptop and I want to copy a shared file into it.

[image]

I checked this file transfer using a **LAN cable** which is reported to have **1 Gbps** connection speed. The copy has approximately **30 Mega Bytes per second** speed. Then I checked it using **Wi-Fi** with 5 GHz frequency  which is reported to have **300 Mbps** connection speed. The copy has around **3 Mega Bytes per second** speed.

I changed the Wi-Fi configurations in the router like Channels and 802.11n Rate but they are all the same.

Why is my Wi-Fi connection so slow? How can I speed it up?

Comment: 802.11n connections are well below 1 Gbps.  [You getting 300Mbps is about what you should expect on 802.11n.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009)

Comment: @Ramhound 300Mbps means 37.5 MBps. Why do I get 3 MBps?

Comment: Your units are incorrect.  `802.11n` has a limit of at most `150 Mbits/sec`, if you have a perfect connection, so that means with a perfect connection in a clean room that would be `18.75 MB/sec`.  [Convert Gbps to Bps](https://www.checkyourmath.com/convert/data_rates/per_second/gigabits_bytes_per_second.php).  1 bytes/sec * ( 8 bits/byte) = **8 Bytes/sec**

Comment: My point is there is no way a 802.11n connection is getting 300 Mbps, that is around, 3x faster then the faster connection speed that is possible with 802.11n

Comment: @Ramhound no I use dual band 5 GHz frequency which has a limit of most 300 Mbits/sec. Even 18 MB/sec is good for me. but 3 is so few.

Comment: Note: this has been cross-posted at https://serverfault.com/q/764221/58408

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - I appreciate the heads up.  Now I know that, I know, not to spend anymore time on it.

Comment: I still maintain the problem is the wireless connection.  You are either not actually using 5.0 GHz but 2.4 Ghz or you just have a really poor signal.   After looking more into it, yes 300 Mb/sec would be possible with the hardware you have I didn't factor into the fact some 802.11 engineering into my last couple comments.

Comment: FYI, I closed the copy of this on Server Fault, as it wasn't obviously about a professional network. @MatinLotfaliee In the future, please do not cross-post. Instead, take the time to learn what site is most appropriate for your question and then post it there.

Comment: @EEAA alright. I will.

Comment: I want to help you, but I need more data. What sustained local read and write speeds does your Debian desktop get to the external USB drive? What actual PHY rate is your laptop getting to the AP?…You might have looked at the maximum possible PHY rate of the link (which is limited to 300Mbps in your setup), but you might be too far away from the AP to get that max rate, so we need to know what PHY rate you're actually getting. Last, what IPerf TCP performance do you get between the laptop and the desktop?

Comment: @Spiff Please tell me how to get actual PHY rate in Windows and how to check IPerf TCP performance.

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee I'm not a Windows user; I don't know where Windows reports the real PHY rate; maybe the place you looked really was the real PHY rate, and you were getting the max rate, but I can't be sure. IPerf is a command-line tool you can Google for. You run "iperf -s" on one machine (s is for server), and "iperf -c IPAddress -r" on the other machine (c is for client, -r tells it to do both a client-to-server upload test and then a server-to-client download test; otherwise it just does an upload test). Replace "IPAddress" with the IP address of the IPerf server.

Comment: @Spiff the iperf of my LAN is around 400 Mbps and the iperf of my Wi-Fi is around 160 Mbps. But I still have 3 MB/sec file copy speed on Wifi and 20 MB/sec file copy speed on LAN.

Comment: @MatinLotaliee And your local sustained read and write speeds from Debian to the external USB disk?

Comment: @Spiff it is 72 MB/sec